# Joining xts objects using try fails in R

Tags: r, merge, try-catch, xts, quantmod

My aim is to download stock prices using the quantmod library for a large number of ticker symbols (~700) and merge the results in a single dataframe which I will save as a csv file.  I have a list of ticker symbols but not all of them are downloadable by quantmod.

So when I pass the list with the ticker symbols to the getSymbols() method, once it encounters a problem with a particular ticker symbol it stops and returns an exception.  I am trying to circumvent this behavior with a for loop and the try method, but I fail.

Let's look at some code:

When I try to download two ticker symbols that are downloadable and then merge them into one xts object I succeed:

```
library(quantmod)
df = getSymbols('AA', from = '1993-06-01', to = '2019-04-16', auto.assign = FALSE)
df1 = getSymbols('A', from = '1993-06-01', to = '2019-04-16', auto.assign = FALSE)
df_all = merge(df, df1, join = 'left')
```

[image]

However my implementation of a combination of a for loop and try methods fails and returns bizarre (to me) results:

```
stocks = c('A', 'AAN', 'AAP', 'AAPL', 'ABBV', 'ABC',  'ABK', 'ABMD', 'ABT',  'ACC', 'ACE', 'ACIW', 'ACM', 'ACN', 'ACS', 'ACV',  'ADBE', 
           'ADI', 'ADM', 'ADP', 'ADS', 'ADSK', 'ADT', 'AEE', 'AEO', 'AEP', 'AES', 'AET', 'AFG', 'AFL', 'AGCO', 'AGN', 'AHL', 'AIG', 'AIV', 'AIZ', 'AJG', 'AKAM', 'AKRX', 'ALB', 'ALEX', 'ALGN', 'ALK', 'ALL', 'ALLE', 'ALTR', 'ALXN', 'AMAT', 'AMCX', 'AMD', 'AME', 'AMG', 'AMGN', 'AMP', 'AMR', 'AMSC', 'AMT', 'AMZN', 'AN', 'ANDW', 'ANF', 'ANR', 'ANSS', 'AOC', 'AOS', 'APA', 'APC', 'APD', 'APH', 'APOL', 'APU', 'ARE', 'ARG', 'ARRS', 'ARW', 'ASH', 'ATI', 'ATVI', 'AVB', 'AVGO', 'AVP', 'AVY', 'AW', 'AWK', 'AXP', 'AYE', 'AYI', 'AZO', 'BA', 'BAC', 'BAX', 'BBBY', 'BBT', 'BBY', 'BC', 'BCR', 'BDK', 'BDX', 'BEN', 'BF.B', 'BHF', 'BHI', 'BIG', 'BIIB', 'BJS', 'BK', 'BKE', 'BLK', 'BLL', 'BMC', 'BMS', 'BMY', 'BNI', 'BRCM', 'BRK.A', 'BRL', 'BRLI', 'BSC', 'BSX', 'BTU', 'BUD', 'BWA', 'BXP', 'C', 'CA', 'CAG', 'CAH', 'CAM', 'CAT', 'CB', 'CBE', 'CBG', 'CBOE', 'CBS', 'CCE', 'CCE_1', 'CCI', 'CCL', 'CCU', 'CDNS', 'CEG', 'CELG', 'CERN', 'CF', 'CFC', 'CFG', 'CFN', 'CHD', 'CHK', 'CHRW', 'CI', 'CIEN', 'CINF', 'CIT', 'CL', 'CLF', 'CLX', 'CMA', 'CMCSA', 'CME', 'CMG', 'CMI', 'CMS', 'CMVT', 'CNC', 'CNO', 'CNP', 'CNX', 'COF', 'COG', 'COH', 'COL', 'COO', 'COP', 'COST', 'COTY', 'COV', 'CPB', 'CPN', 'CPWR', 'CR', 'CRA', 'CRM', 'CRVL', 'CSC', 'CSCO', 'CSRA', 'CSX', 'CTAS', 'CTL', 'CTSH', 'CTX', 'CTXS', 'CVC', 'CVG', 'CVH', 'CVS', 'CVX', 'CXO', 'CZN', 'D', 'DAL', 'DCI', 'DD', 'DDR', 'DDS', 'DE', 'DELL', 'DF', 'DFS', 'DGX', 'DG_1', 'DHI', 'DHR', 'DIS', 'DISCA', 'DISH', 'DLPH', 'DLR', 'DLTR', 'DNB', 'DNR', 'DO', 'DOV', 'DOW', 'DPS', 'DRE', 'DRI', 'DTE', 'DTV', 'DUK', 'DV', 'DVA', 'DVN', 'DYN', 'EBAY', 'ECL', 'ED', 'EDS', 'EFX', 'EIX', 'EK', 'EL', 'EMC', 'EMN', 'EMR', 'ENDP', 'EOG', 'EP', 'EQ', 'EQIX', 'EQR', 'EQT', 'ERTS', 'ESRX', 'ESS', 'ESV', 'ETFC', 'ETN', 'ETR', 'EW', 'EXC', 'EXPD', 'EXPE', 'EXR', 'F', 'FAST', 'FB', 'FBHS', 'FCX', 'FDO', 'FDS', 'FDX', 'FE', 'FFIV', 'FHN', 'FII', 'FIS', 'FISV', 'FITB', 'FL', 'FLIR', 'FLR', 'FLS', 'FMC', 'FNM', 'FO', 'FOSL', 'FPL', 'FRE', 'FRT', 'FRX', 'FSLR', 'FTI', 'FTV', 'GAS', 'GAS_0', 'GCI', 'GCI_0', 'GD', 'GE', 'GENZ', 'GGP', 'GGP_0', 'GILD', 'GIS', 'GLAD', 'GLW', 'GM', 'GME', 'GM_0', 'GNW', 'GOOG', 'GPC', 'GPN', 'GPS', 'GR', 'GRA', 'GRMN', 'GS', 'GT', 'GWW', 'HAL', 'HAR', 'HAS', 'HBAN', 'HBI', 'HCA', 'HCBK', 'HCN', 'HCP', 'HD', 'HES', 'HIBB', 'HIG', 'HLT', 'HNZ', 'HOG', 'HOLX', 'HON', 'HOT', 'HP', 'HPC', 'HPE', 'HPQ', 'HRB', 'HRL', 'HRS', 'HSIC', 'HSP', 'HST', 'HSY', 'HUM', 'IACI', 'IBM', 'ICE', 'IDXX', 'IFF', 'IGT', 'ILMN', 'INCY', 'INFO', 'INTC', 'INTU', 'IP', 'IPG', 'IR', 'IRM', 'ISRG', 'IT', 'ITT', 'ITW', 'IVZ', 'JAVA', 'JBHT', 'JBL', 'JCI', 'JCP', 'JDSU', 'JEC', 'JNJ', 'JNPR', 'JNS', 'JNY', 'JPM', 'JWN', 'K', 'KBH', 'KEY', 'KFT', 'KG', 'KHC', 'KIM', 'KLAC', 'KMB', 'KMI', 'KMX', 'KO', 'KORS', 'KR', 'KRFT', 'KSS', 'KSU', 'LEG', 'LEH_0', 'LEN', 'LH', 'LIFE', 'LIZ', 'LKQ', 'LLL', 'LLTC', 'LLY', 'LM', 'LMT', 'LNC', 'LNKD', 'LNT', 'LOW', 'LRCX', 'LSI', 'LSTR', 'LTD', 'LTR', 'LUK', 'LUV', 'LVLT', 'LXK', 'LYB', 'M', 'MA', 'MAA', 'MAC', 'MAR', 'MAS', 'MAT', 'MBI', 'MCD', 'MCHP', 'MCK', 'MCO', 'MDP', 'MDT', 'MED', 'MER', 'MET', 'MFE', 'MGM', 'MHK', 'MHP', 'MHS', 'MI', 'MIL', 'MJN', 'MKC', 'MLM', 'MMC', 'MMM', 'MNK', 'MNST', 'MNST_0', 'MO', 'MOLX', 'MON', 'MOS', 'MOT', 'MPC', 'MRK', 'MRO', 'MS', 'MSFT', 'MTB', 'MTD', 'MTG', 'MTW', 'MU', 'MUR', 'MWV', 'MYL', 'NAV', 'NAVI', 'NBL', 'NBR', 'NCC', 'NCLH', 'NDAQ', 'NE', 'NEM', 'NFLX', 'NFX', 'NI', 'NILE', 'NKE', 'NLSN', 'NOC', 'NOV', 'NOVL', 'NRG', 'NSC', 'NSM', 'NTAP', 'NTRS', 'NU', 'NUE', 'NUS', 'NVDA', 'NVLS', 'NWL', 'NWS.A', 'NWS', 'NYT', 'NYX', 'O', 'ODP', 'OFLX', 'OI', 'OKE', 'OMC', 'OMX', 'ORCL', 'ORLY', 'OXY', 'PAYX', 'PBCT', 'PBG', 'PBI', 'PCAR', 'PCG', 'PCL', 'PCLN', 'PCP', 'PDCO', 'PEG', 'PEP', 'PETM', 'PETS', 'PFE', 'PFG', 'PFIE', 'PG', 'PGN', 'PGR', 'PH', 'PHM', 'PKG', 'PKI', 'PLD',
           'PLD_0', 'PLL', 'PM', 'PMTC', 'PNC', 'PNR', 'PNW', 'POM', 'PPG', 'PPL', 'PRGO', 'PRU', 'PSA', 'PSX', 'PTV', 'PVH', 'PWR', 'PX', 'PXD', 'PYPL', 'Q', 'QCOM', 'QLGC', 'QRVO', 'QSII', 'Q_1', 'R', 'RAD', 'RAI', 'RAVN', 'RCL', 'RDC', 'RE', 'REG', 'REGN', 'RF', 'RHI', 'RHT', 'RIG', 'RJF', 'RL', 'RMD', 'ROH', 'ROK', 'ROP', 'ROST', 'RRC', 'RRD', 'RSG', 'RSH', 'RTN', 'RX', 'S', 'SAF', 'SAI', 'SAM', 'SANM', 'SAPE', 'SBAC', 'SBL', 'SBUX', 'SCG', 'SCHW', 'SE', 'SEE', 'SGP', 'SHLD', 'SHW', 'SIAL', 'SIG', 'SII', 'SJM', 'SLB', 'SLE', 'SLG', 'SLM', 'SNA', 'SNDK', 'SNI', 'SNPS', 'SO', 'SOV', 'SPG', 'SPLS', 'SRCL', 'SRE', 'SSP', 'STI', 'STJ', 'STR', 'STT', 'STX', 'STZ', 'SUN', 'SVU', 'SWK', 'SWKS', 'SWN', 'SWY', 'SYF', 'SYK', 'SYMC', 'SYNT', 'SYY', 'T', 'TAP', 'TDC', 'TDG', 'TE', 'TEG', 'TEL', 'TER', 'TEX', 'TGT', 'THC', 'TIE', 'TIF', 'TIN', 'TJX', 'TKR', 'TLAB', 'TMK', 'TMO', 'TRIP', 'TROW', 'TRV', 'TSCO', 'TSLA', 'TSN', 'TSO', 'TSS', 'TT', 'TWC', 'TWTR', 'TWX', 'TXN', 'TXT', 'TYC', 'UA', 'UAL', 'UDR', 'UG', 'UHS', 'UIS', 'ULTA', 'UNH', 'UNM', 'UNP', 'UPS', 'URBN', 'URI', 'USB', 'UST', 'UTX', 'V', 'VAR', 'VFC', 'VIA.B', 'VIVO', 'VLO', 'VMC', 'VNO', 'VRSK', 'VRSN', 'VRTX', 'VTR', 'VZ', 'WAG', 'WAT', 'WB', 'WBA', 'WDC', 'WDR', 'WEC', 'WEN', 'WFC', 'WFMI', 'WFR', 'WFT', 'WHR', 'WIN', 'WINA', 'WLP', 'WLTW', 'WM', 'WMB', 'WMT', 'WM_0', 'WPI', 'WPO', 'WPX', 'WRK', 'WU', 'WWY', 'WY', 'WYE', 'WYN', 'WYNN', 'X', 'XEC', 'XEL', 'XL', 'XLNX', 'XOM', 'XRAY', 'XRX', 'XTO', 'XYL', 'YHOO', 'YUM', 'ZION', 'ZMH', 'ZTS')

data =getSymbols('AA', from = '1993-06-01', to = '2019-04-16', auto.assign = FALSE)


for(stock in stocks){

   dat = try(getSymbols(stock, from = '1993-06-01', to = '2019-04-16'))

   if (length(dat) > 0){

     data = merge(data, dat, join = 'left')

   }

}
```

This returns an object which looks like that:

[image]

```
> dim(data)
[1] 6516  766


> colnames(data)
  [1] "AA.Open"     "AA.High"     "AA.Low"      "AA.Close"    "AA.Volume"   "AA.Adjusted" "dat"         "dat.1"      
  [9] "dat.2"       "dat.3"       "dat.4"       "dat.5"       "dat.6"       "dat.7"       "dat.8"       "dat.9"      
 [17] "dat.10"      "dat.11"      "dat.12"      "dat.13"      "dat.14"      "dat.15"      "dat.16"      "dat.17"     
 [25] "dat.18"      "dat.19"      "dat.20"      "dat.21"      "dat.22"      "dat.23"      "dat.24"      "dat.25"     
 [33] "dat.26"      "dat.27"      "dat.28"      "dat.29"      "dat.30"      "dat.31"      "dat.32"      "dat.33"     
 [41] "dat.34"      "dat.35"      "dat.36"      "dat.37"      "dat.38"      "dat.39"      "dat.40"      "dat.41"     
 [49] "dat.42"      "dat.43"      "dat.44"      "dat.45"      "dat.46"      "dat.47"      "dat.48"      "dat.49"     
 [57] "dat.50"      "dat.51"      "dat.52"      "dat.53"      "dat.54"      "dat.55"      "dat.56"      "dat.57"     
 [65] "dat.58"      "dat.59"      "dat.60"      "dat.61"      "dat.62"      "dat.63"      "dat.64"      "dat.65"     
 [73] "dat.66"      "dat.67"      "dat.68"      "dat.69"      "dat.70"      "dat.71"      "dat.72"      "dat.73"     
 [81] "dat.74"      "dat.75"      "dat.76"      "dat.77"      "dat.78"      "dat.79"      "dat.80"      "dat.81"     
 [89] "dat.82"      "dat.83"      "dat.84"      "dat.85"      "dat.86"      "dat.87"      "dat.88"      "dat.89"     
 [97] "dat.90"      "dat.91"      "dat.92"      "dat.93"      "dat.94"      "dat.95"      "dat.96"      "dat.97"     
[105] "dat.98"      "dat.99"      "dat.100"     "dat.101"     "dat.102"     "dat.103"     "dat.104"     "dat.105"    
[113] "dat.106"     "dat.107"     "dat.108"     "dat.109"     "dat.110"     "dat.111"     "dat.112"     "dat.113"    
[121] "dat.114"     "dat.115"     "dat.116"     "dat.117"     "dat.118"     "dat.119"     "dat.120"     "dat.121"    
[129] "dat.122"     "dat.123"     "dat.124"     "dat.125"     "dat.126"     "dat.127"     "dat.128"     "dat.129"    
[137] "dat.130"     "dat.131"     "dat.132"     "dat.133"     "dat.134"     "dat.135"     "dat.136"     "dat.137"    
[145] "dat.138"     "dat.139"     "dat.140"     "dat.141"     "dat.142"     "dat.143"     "dat.144"     "dat.145"    
[153] "dat.146"     "dat.147"     "dat.148"     "dat.149"     "dat.150"     "dat.151"     "dat.152"     "dat.153"    
[161] "dat.154"     "dat.155"     "dat.156"     "dat.157"     "dat.158"     "dat.159"     "dat.160"     "dat.161"    
[169] "dat.162"     "dat.163"     "dat.164"     "dat.165"     "dat.166"     "dat.167"     "dat.168"     "dat.169"    
[177] "dat.170"     "dat.171"     "dat.172"     "dat.173"     "dat.174"     "dat.175"     "dat.176"     "dat.177"    
[185] "dat.178"     "dat.179"     "dat.180"     "dat.181"     "dat.182"     "dat.183"     "dat.184"     "dat.185"    
[193] "dat.186"     "dat.187"     "dat.188"     "dat.189"     "dat.190"     "dat.191"     "dat.192"     "dat.193"    
[201] "dat.194"     "dat.195"     "dat.196"     "dat.197"     "dat.198"     "dat.199"     "dat.200"     "dat.201"    
[209] "dat.202"     "dat.203"     "dat.204"     "dat.205"     "dat.206"     "dat.207"     "dat.208"     "dat.209"    
[217] "dat.210"     "dat.211"     "dat.212"     "dat.213"     "dat.214"     "dat.215"     "dat.216"     "dat.217"    
[225] "dat.218"     "dat.219"     "dat.220"     "dat.221"     "dat.222"     "dat.223"     "dat.224"     "dat.225"    
[233] "dat.226"     "dat.227"     "dat.228"     "dat.229"     "dat.230"     "dat.231"     "dat.232"     "dat.233"    
[241] "dat.234"     "dat.235"     "dat.236"     "dat.237"     "dat.238"     "dat.239"     "dat.240"     "dat.241"    
[249] "dat.242"     "dat.243"     "dat.244"     "dat.245"     "dat.246"     "dat.247"     "dat.248"     "dat.249"    
[257] "dat.250"     "dat.251"     "dat.252"     "dat.253"     "dat.254"     "dat.255"     "dat.256"     "dat.257"    
[265] "dat.258"     "dat.259"     "dat.260"     "dat.261"     "dat.262"     "dat.263"     "dat.264"     "dat.265"    
[273] "dat.266"     "dat.267"     "dat.268"     "dat.269"     "dat.270"     "dat.271"     "dat.272"     "dat.273"    
[281] "dat.274"     "dat.275"     "dat.276"     "dat.277"     "dat.278"     "dat.279"     "dat.280"     "dat.281"    
[289] "dat.282"     "dat.283"     "dat.284"     "dat.285"     "dat.286"     "dat.287"     "dat.288"     "dat.289"    
[297] "dat.290"     "dat.291"     "dat.292"     "dat.293"     "dat.294"     "dat.295"     "dat.296"     "dat.297"    
[305] "dat.298"     "dat.299"     "dat.300"     "dat.301"     "dat.302"     "dat.303"     "dat.304"     "dat.305"    
[313] "dat.306"     "dat.307"     "dat.308"     "dat.309"     "dat.310"     "dat.311"     "dat.312"     "dat.313"    
[321] "dat.314"     "dat.315"     "dat.316"     "dat.317"     "dat.318"     "dat.319"     "dat.320"     "dat.321"    
[329] "dat.322"     "dat.323"     "dat.324"     "dat.325"     "dat.326"     "dat.327"     "dat.328"     "dat.329"    
[337] "dat.330"     "dat.331"     "dat.332"     "dat.333"     "dat.334"     "dat.335"     "dat.336"     "dat.337"    
[345] "dat.338"     "dat.339"     "dat.340"     "dat.341"     "dat.342"     "dat.343"     "dat.344"     "dat.345"    
[353] "dat.346"     "dat.347"     "dat.348"     "dat.349"     "dat.350"     "dat.351"     "dat.352"     "dat.353"    
[361] "dat.354"     "dat.355"     "dat.356"     "dat.357"     "dat.358"     "dat.359"     "dat.360"     "dat.361"    
[369] "dat.362"     "dat.363"     "dat.364"     "dat.365"     "dat.366"     "dat.367"     "dat.368"     "dat.369"    
[377] "dat.370"     "dat.371"     "dat.372"     "dat.373"     "dat.374"     "dat.375"     "dat.376"     "dat.377"    
[385] "dat.378"     "dat.379"     "dat.380"     "dat.381"     "dat.382"     "dat.383"     "dat.384"     "dat.385"    
[393] "dat.386"     "dat.387"     "dat.388"     "dat.389"     "dat.390"     "dat.391"     "dat.392"     "dat.393"    
[401] "dat.394"     "dat.395"     "dat.396"     "dat.397"     "dat.398"     "dat.399"     "dat.400"     "dat.401"    
[409] "dat.402"     "dat.403"     "dat.404"     "dat.405"     "dat.406"     "dat.407"     "dat.408"     "dat.409"    
[417] "dat.410"     "dat.411"     "dat.412"     "dat.413"     "dat.414"     "dat.415"     "dat.416"     "dat.417"    
[425] "dat.418"     "dat.419"     "dat.420"     "dat.421"     "dat.422"     "dat.423"     "dat.424"     "dat.425"    
[433] "dat.426"     "dat.427"     "dat.428"     "dat.429"     "dat.430"     "dat.431"     "dat.432"     "dat.433"    
[441] "dat.434"     "dat.435"     "dat.436"     "dat.437"     "dat.438"     "dat.439"     "dat.440"     "dat.441"    
[449] "dat.442"     "dat.443"     "dat.444"     "dat.445"     "dat.446"     "dat.447"     "dat.448"     "dat.449"    
[457] "dat.450"     "dat.451"     "dat.452"     "dat.453"     "dat.454"     "dat.455"     "dat.456"     "dat.457"    
[465] "dat.458"     "dat.459"     "dat.460"     "dat.461"     "dat.462"     "dat.463"     "dat.464"     "dat.465"    
[473] "dat.466"     "dat.467"     "dat.468"     "dat.469"     "dat.470"     "dat.471"     "dat.472"     "dat.473"    
[481] "dat.474"     "dat.475"     "dat.476"     "dat.477"     "dat.478"     "dat.479"     "dat.480"     "dat.481"    
[489] "dat.482"     "dat.483"     "dat.484"     "dat.485"     "dat.486"     "dat.487"     "dat.488"     "dat.489"    
[497] "dat.490"     "dat.491"     "dat.492"     "dat.493"     "dat.494"     "dat.495"     "dat.496"     "dat.497"    
[505] "dat.498"     "dat.499"     "dat.500"     "dat.501"     "dat.502"     "dat.503"     "dat.504"     "dat.505"    
[513] "dat.506"     "dat.507"     "dat.508"     "dat.509"     "dat.510"     "dat.511"     "dat.512"     "dat.513"    
[521] "dat.514"     "dat.515"     "dat.516"     "dat.517"     "dat.518"     "dat.519"     "dat.520"     "dat.521"    
[529] "dat.522"     "dat.523"     "dat.524"     "dat.525"     "dat.526"     "dat.527"     "dat.528"     "dat.529"    
[537] "dat.530"     "dat.531"     "dat.532"     "dat.533"     "dat.534"     "dat.535"     "dat.536"     "dat.537"    
[545] "dat.538"     "dat.539"     "dat.540"     "dat.541"     "dat.542"     "dat.543"     "dat.544"     "dat.545"    
[553] "dat.546"     "dat.547"     "dat.548"     "dat.549"     "dat.550"     "dat.551"     "dat.552"     "dat.553"    
[561] "dat.554"     "dat.555"     "dat.556"     "dat.557"     "dat.558"     "dat.559"     "dat.560"     "dat.561"    
[569] "dat.562"     "dat.563"     "dat.564"     "dat.565"     "dat.566"     "dat.567"     "dat.568"     "dat.569"    
[577] "dat.570"     "dat.571"     "dat.572"     "dat.573"     "dat.574"     "dat.575"     "dat.576"     "dat.577"    
[585] "dat.578"     "dat.579"     "dat.580"     "dat.581"     "dat.582"     "dat.583"     "dat.584"     "dat.585"    
[593] "dat.586"     "dat.587"     "dat.588"     "dat.589"     "dat.590"     "dat.591"     "dat.592"     "dat.593"    
[601] "dat.594"     "dat.595"     "dat.596"     "dat.597"     "dat.598"     "dat.599"     "dat.600"     "dat.601"    
[609] "dat.602"     "dat.603"     "dat.604"     "dat.605"     "dat.606"     "dat.607"     "dat.608"     "dat.609"    
[617] "dat.610"     "dat.611"     "dat.612"     "dat.613"     "dat.614"     "dat.615"     "dat.616"     "dat.617"    
[625] "dat.618"     "dat.619"     "dat.620"     "dat.621"     "dat.622"     "dat.623"     "dat.624"     "dat.625"    
[633] "dat.626"     "dat.627"     "dat.628"     "dat.629"     "dat.630"     "dat.631"     "dat.632"     "dat.633"    
[641] "dat.634"     "dat.635"     "dat.636"     "dat.637"     "dat.638"     "dat.639"     "dat.640"     "dat.641"    
[649] "dat.642"     "dat.643"     "dat.644"     "dat.645"     "dat.646"     "dat.647"     "dat.648"     "dat.649"    
[657] "dat.650"     "dat.651"     "dat.652"     "dat.653"     "dat.654"     "dat.655"     "dat.656"     "dat.657"    
[665] "dat.658"     "dat.659"     "dat.660"     "dat.661"     "dat.662"     "dat.663"     "dat.664"     "dat.665"    
[673] "dat.666"     "dat.667"     "dat.668"     "dat.669"     "dat.670"     "dat.671"     "dat.672"     "dat.673"    
[681] "dat.674"     "dat.675"     "dat.676"     "dat.677"     "dat.678"     "dat.679"     "dat.680"     "dat.681"    
[689] "dat.682"     "dat.683"     "dat.684"     "dat.685"     "dat.686"     "dat.687"     "dat.688"     "dat.689"    
[697] "dat.690"     "dat.691"     "dat.692"     "dat.693"     "dat.694"     "dat.695"     "dat.696"     "dat.697"    
[705] "dat.698"     "dat.699"     "dat.700"     "dat.701"     "dat.702"     "dat.703"     "dat.704"     "dat.705"    
[713] "dat.706"     "dat.707"     "dat.708"     "dat.709"     "dat.710"     "dat.711"     "dat.712"     "dat.713"    
[721] "dat.714"     "dat.715"     "dat.716"     "dat.717"     "dat.718"     "dat.719"     "dat.720"     "dat.721"    
[729] "dat.722"     "dat.723"     "dat.724"     "dat.725"     "dat.726"     "dat.727"     "dat.728"     "dat.729"    
[737] "dat.730"     "dat.731"     "dat.732"     "dat.733"     "dat.734"     "dat.735"     "dat.736"     "dat.737"    
[745] "dat.738"     "dat.739"     "dat.740"     "dat.741"     "dat.742"     "dat.743"     "dat.744"     "dat.745"    
[753] "dat.746"     "dat.747"     "dat.748"     "dat.749"     "dat.750"     "dat.751"     "dat.752"     "dat.753"    
[761] "dat.754"     "dat.755"     "dat.756"     "dat.757"     "dat.758"     "dat.759"
```

Comment: I guess the issue is `dat = try(getSymbols(stock, from = '1993-06-01', to = '2019-04-16'))`. You need `auto.assign = T`

Comment: @amatsuo_net, actually `auto.assign = FALSE` in the try statement otherwise it creates an object in the environment and doesn't bind it to dat. Also built in a timer as yahoo might block too many fast requests. You might want to look at the package BatchGetSymbols.

Comment: Oops. What I meant was `auto.assign = FALSE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code I tried. It seems working (although I tried only a subset of the vector):

```r
data <- getSymbols('AA', from = '1993-06-01', to = '2019-04-16', auto.assign = FALSE)

for(stock in stocks){
  cat(paste0("processing: ", stock, "\n"))
  dat <- NULL
  try({
    dat <- getSymbols(stock, from = '1993-06-01', to = '2019-04-16', auto.assign = FALSE)
    if (length(dat) > 0){
      data <- merge(data, dat, join = 'left')
    }
  })
}
```